# How see total app installs on iTunes Connect?

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, itunes-store

I see on iTunes Connect in AppAnalytics/SalesAndTrends sections only app units (that means the difference of app installs from previous week/month).
Where can I see the total app installs number?
Thanks

Comment: You can check total installed by date filter.

Comment: Switch to Android, it easier there :)

Comment: @Pramod Tapaniya thanks sounds great, i'll accept answer if you will write it as answer

Comment: @tatiana_c see my answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

iTunes Connect provide a date filter for how many time apps were installed during a particular time period. You can use that filter for this situation.

Comment: the limit is 1 year span though

Comment: @Mirko Sorry, not understand.

Comment: you cannot see the total number of installs since you release the app, as the date filter does not allow you to select more than 1-year span. Our app was released 3 years ago, we cannot get the overall total but just the total for the past year.

Comment: don't select "Last 365 days" option, Use "Custom Range" option. By that you can see any period of time.

Comment: Custom range is 1 year span max.

Comment: I hope you are checking in https://reportingitc2.apple.com/sales.html page.

Comment: @Mirko now you can select custom range more than 1 year ago

Answer (score 30):

As of this post I was able to get lifetime numbers. From the App Store Connect dashboard nagivate to 'Sales and Trends'. From there click 'Units' (left nav, under 'Sales'). Then click the date selection input- 'Lifetime' should appear in the date selection popover.